# Pass array as parameter key in Swift using Alamofire

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parameter-passing, alamofire

I am trying to pass array as key in the parameter but i am getting below error:

The underlying encoder failed with the error: invalidRootObject("array([Alamofire.URLEncodedFormComponent.array([Alamofire.URLEncodedFormComponent.string("link")]), Alamofire.URLEncodedFormComponent.string("24")])")

Here is my code for parameter:

```
      let parameters: [[String]: String] = [
        ["link"]: linkId
    ]
```

[image: Postman Pic]

Comment: `URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody, arrayEncoding: .brackets, boolEncoding: .literal)` might do the trick, but it's escaping the bracklets, so I'm note sure it's fully working.

Answer (score 0):

`URLEncoding` handles by default the `Array` type as a **value** of a `Dictionary` in parameters (not as a **key** like in your example code) It even adds the brackets in the key by default.

So, something like this should work fine:

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
    "links": [84, 11, 83, 24]
]
AF.request(url, method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).response { response in
    // ...
}
```